# Replace text on every selected line in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, textarea

I have a textarea in my HTML where users can type something. There is a button near the textarea that adds a ' - ' to the beginning of a selected line to make it like a list.

For example if I have the following text:

`This is a line of text`

And I selected it all and pressed the button it would appear like this:

`- This is a line of text`

However, this only works when selecting one line. If I was to select two lines, it will only format the one line. Here is my code:

**Javascript with some jQuery:**

```
var selection = $("#answer" + questionNumber).getSelection();
if (selection.text != '') {
    $("#answer" + questionNumber).replaceSelectedText('  - ' + selection.text);
    return;
}
```

The `.getSelection()` and `.replaceSelectedText()` methods come from [this](https://github.com/timdown/rangyinputs) jQuery plugin.

I though maybe by identifying if there are '\n' in the selection then adding the list styling to it, perhaps using regex, though I'm not sure how to go about coding that.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/1o96s17w/) is a JSFiddle of my issue.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or plunker?

Comment: @A.J I tried to make one https://jsfiddle.net/PavSidhu/s2o33zzj/ but I cannot import the required files in the `<script>` tags for some reason.

Comment: @PavSidhu You add the resources on the left....

Comment: Your jsfiddle has a few errors in it, including the fact that you are trying to load your scripts over regular http in an iframe on a secure page (it even warns you if you look in the dev console). I've cleaned up the issues and forked your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1o96s17w/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your current code does is add a `-` to the beginning of the selected text. If you want to substitute something throughout your string, JavaScript's `replace` function with a regular expression can be a simple way to do it. Try:

```
var newText = selection.text.replace(/^/gm, '  - ');
$("#answer" + questionNumber).replaceSelectedText(newText);
```

I've tweaked your fiddle with a [proof of concept](https://jsfiddle.net/1o96s17w/5/).

Details:

- The `^` character matches the beginning of a line.
- The `/m` option tells JavaScript that you care about multiple lines - otherwise `^` matches only the very beginning of the string.
- The `/g` option does a global replace. That is, replaces every occurrence, not just the first one.

More docs on JS regular expressions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Also, (I will add this to the question if you manage to answer) is there a way to stop adding '  - ' to a line if it is already there?

Comment: That might be worthy of a separate question, and I'd recommend learning more about regular expressions. https://regex101.com/#javascript is a good place to experiment. Something like `/^[^-\s]+/`will not match lines that start with whitespace and dashes: https://regex101.com/r/fU7rB0/1

Answer (score 1):

A fairly straightforward solution is to use a regex to replace all newlines in the selected text:

```
var replacementText = '  - ' + selection.text.replace(/\n(.*)/g, "\n  - $1");
```

This searches for any newline `\n` characters, captures any content on the line after it `(.*)`, and then reinserts it with a bullet point `-` separating the newline and captured content. the `g` flag matches all cases.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1o96s17w/3/) for a working example.

Note that this solution should preserve most of the existing behaviour of your code. One eccentricity is that if the last character in your selection is a newline character, it will add a bullet point to the line below, which may not be desirable. To get rid of this you could modify the regex so that it ignores newline characters that border the end of the selected string ([example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1o96s17w/6/)):

```
// Includes a check to ignore newlines that are not followed
// by at least one character of any kind
selection.text.replace(/\n(?!$(?![\s\S]))(.*)/g, "\n  - $1")
```

I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to get the exact behaviour you want. The above examples should help you to get started at least. In any case, I would highly suggest refactoring the replacement logic and unit testing it thoroughly to ensure consistent behaviour.